# Utility of staging unmodified files using Git?

Tags: git

*I'm relatively new to git SCM.  By accident, I discovered that it is possible to stage unmodified files.*

After making minor changes to a broad file set, I checked status (`git status`) then manually staged what I thought was my change set...

```
git add file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

...only to realize prior to committing that `file2` had **not** been modified.

I removed `file2` from the staged set and proceeded with my commit, but now I'm wondering what purpose might there be to committing unmodified file(s)?

Comment: I tried that, and couldn't get it to show up with `git status` afterwards. I'm pretty sure that staging an unmodified but tracked file is a no-op.

Comment: However, there is a `--intent-to-add` option to `git add` which simply stages a *new* file, but without its content.

Comment: why do you think that the file was not modified?

Comment: @Chronial, the file was not listed when I initially checked `git status`.  @jpaugh, I cannot reproduce this myself now...will play with this a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been noted, staging an unmodified file is a no-op

```sh
$ git status
# On branch gh-pages
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git add README

$ git status
# On branch gh-pages
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: Thanks folks.  I'd come to the same conclusion using `--verbose` to watch the file add a bit closer.  Cheers!